# Extracting jfif image from 2d barcode

Tags: image-processing, barcode, binaryfiles

I have data read from 2d bar code pdf417. It contains an embedded image in the format of (jfif), The image is not at the beginning of the decoded data it has some data fields and the image is somewhere after, the data fields does not seam to have fixed lengths. How can I extract the Image from the decoded data. I used ClearImage Library to decode the barcode and I have it as text and Hex.
Please help. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

I was able to extract the image thanks to many experts in StackOverflow, I have being reviewing their posts. The following code explains how to extract the image from a mixed binary file, the code is not so beautiful but it can do the job. It searches for (JFIF) image header and extracts it into an image file.

```
public static void ExtractImage(string fname)
{
try
{
FileStream fs = new FileStream(fname, FileMode.Open);
BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs);
//read the first binary
char[] soi="Empty".ToCharArray();
br.BaseStream.Position = 0;
long imgpos = 0;
ushort r = 0;
while ((r = br.ReadUInt16())> 0)
{
Console.WriteLine(r);
if (r == 0xd8ff)
{
Console.WriteLine("Detcted----->");
imgpos = br.BaseStream.Position;
break;
//UInt16 jfif = br.ReadUInt16(); // JFIF marker
//Console.WriteLine("jfif " + jfif);
//if (jfif == 0xe0ff || jfif == 57855)
//    Console.WriteLine(" also Detected--->");
}
}
//now copy to stream
FileStream str = new FileStream("bcimage.jpg", FileMode.OpenOrCreate,   FileAccess.Write);
BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(str);
br.BaseStream.Position = imgpos-2;
int l = (int)(fs.Length - imgpos - 2);
bw.Write(br.ReadBytes(l));
fs.Close();
br.Close();
}
catch (Exception exp)
{
MessageBox.Show(exp.Message);
}
}
```

Comment: The code assumes that the image object is the last object in the binary file, if it is not the case then you have to modify the code to search for other segments of the image markers that describes the image size.